# SpriteKit Transition Won't Work

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add a transition to my SpriteKit scene, but it won't work. My second scene is called "myScene." Here's my code:

```
  func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let collision:UInt32 = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)

    if collision == (playerCategory | crateCategory) {

        NSLog("Game Over")
        self.scene?.view?.paused = true
        var myscene = myScene(size: self.size)
        var transition = SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        myscene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
        self.scene!.view?.presentScene(myscene, transition: transition)

    }
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bubbleCategory) {
        let node = contact.bodyB.node
        //Other remove routine
        node?.removeAllActions()
        node?.removeFromParent()
    } else if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == bubbleCategory) {
        let node = contact.bodyB.node
        //Other remove routine
        node?.removeAllActions()
        node?.removeFromParent()
    }


}
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will present the scene and it works fine for me every time. This will not return nil for the scene so it will transition smoothly. You can also set ignoreSiblingOrder to whatever you want with this line: `skView?.ignoresSiblingOrder = true //or false`
Here is my GameScene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        println("touch occured in gamescene")

        let scene:SKScene = myScene()
        let skView = self.view as SKView?
        skView!.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene.size = skView!.bounds.size
        skView!.presentScene(scene)


    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

}

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82223/discussion-on-answer-by-thecodecomposer-spritekit-transition-wont-work).